# Validar un registro antes de guardar datos en Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Para que los usuarios se puedan registrar en el sistema, el administrador debe otorgarles un código que éste registra en la BD en la tabla 'codigos', luego cuando el usuario está llenando el form de registro debe introducir dicho código en el campo "código", valga la redundancia, y al momento de guardar los datos necesito que el sistema valide que el código que introdujo el usuario coincide con alguno ya registrado en la tabla 'codigos', de lo contrario no podrá registrarse.

Pudiera hacerlo haciendo una consulta en la BD en el controlador antes de guardar el registro, la cuestión es que estoy usando Devise para la autenticación y registro de usuarios, y no se me ocurre más nada... Alguien me puede orientar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un controlador que herede de *Devise* y agregar tu lógica ahí; por ejemplo:

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb

class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    validate_code
    super
  end

  private

  def validate_code
    # Agrega tu lógica de validación de código aquí.
  end
end
```

Y luego simplemente debes actualizar tus rutas para que *Devise* utilice el controlador que acabas de crear:

```
# config/routes.rb

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
```

Comment: Al generar el método privado `validate_code` estás aislando un poco la lógica que no es propia del método `create`, separando responsabilidades; sin embargo podrías mejorarlo aún más generando un _Service Object_ que sea el responsable de verificar el código en lugar de usar el método privado.

Comment: Hola Gerry, hice los cambios mientras tenia una sesión de usuario abierta, y al momento de cerrar sesión me apareció el siguiente mensaje: "Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created", por lo que veo tengo que renombrar mi ruta con :as, como lo hago?

Comment: ya lo solucioné, tenía devise_for :user 2 veces en mi archivo de rutas, eliminé uno y me funcionó